# How to create a listview with checkbox settings in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I want to create a tableview with checkboxes for android using titanium mobile. The problem is i dont know how and where i can store and check the state of the checkboxes using javascript in titanium.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use Titanium.App.Properties to save and recall the data. See http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.App.Properties-module

Answer (score 1):

you can use models and collections  for more information you can refer to http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Models